# MongoDB Change Streams: does config FullDocument = UpdateLookup have performance implications on the source DB?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, change-data-capture, changestream

I am trying to deep dive into Mongo Change Streams implementation to understand whether configuring **[full document update lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/changeStreams/#lookup-full-document-for-update-operations) will impact DB performance in a production environment**.

**I assume the full document lookup is just a simple query by ID.** Therefore, my manly concern is how it will impact the source DB when there are a lot of writes happening to it. Maybe there is a configuration to query by batch of IDs, that might help.

**If the change stream cursor will query my collection each time it sees an update in the oplog, it simply means that each applicative write to the collection is effectively a write and a read**. I don't want to impact an operational DB performance and thus impact the application performance.

**From my understanding, change streams reading from the oplog will not impact the DB so much, but if my assumption above is right, this main advantage is gone.**

Setup background:

- I intend to use this leveraging the [Kafka-Connect Native Mongo source connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/), which implements change streams under-the-hoods ([the java-sync driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/r4.3.4/driver-sync/src/main/com/mongodb/client/internal/MongoChangeStreamCursorImpl.java)).
- My source collection is in MongoDB 4.4.
- The source collection does have a lot of writing to it.

Appreciate any piece of information on this matter.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a pipeline with a $match and $project, you can minimize the data returned when a changestream watch fires. It certainly minimizes the data load in your application because you can project just the fields you're interested in as opposed to the whole document. I do not know whether this truly saves bandwidth in the database, because I don't fully understand the inner workings, but it could. Here's how I do it:

```
const pipeline01 = [
    { $match: { 'updateDescription.updatedFields.fieldIamInterestedIn': { $ne: undefined } } },
    { $project: { 'fullDocument._id': 1, 'fullDocument.anotherFieldIamInterestedIn': 1 } },
];
collectionIamWatching.watch(pipeline01, { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }).on('change', async (data) => {
    // then do what you want with data.fullDocument - it will only contain the fields you've named in the $project step
});
```